# Portrait, Landscape in Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am designing with `LinearLayout` which is working for portrait but landscape it does arranged properly. I do not use x,y positions. If I change anything in xml it affects the design -- how do I design both portrait and landscape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a layout-land folder, to put all your landscape layouts (duplicate them, but with little differences in order to they show properly in corresponding orientation). In order to avoid this, you should work with RelativeLayouts. But if it's too late and you don't want to change everything, you can create the mentioned folder and make the proper layout changes.

So you will have a

```
layout/activity.xml
```

and a

```
layout-land/activity.xml
```

If your app is big, it might become a pain to make every change two times, but it's not so bad.

Not recommended, but you can also avoid changing orientation by supporting only portrait orientation in your app: you would have to put "android:screenOrientation="portrait"" in your app's Manifest then.

Comment: thanks, how to specify to the activity take xml for landscape from layout-land

Comment: It is done automatically by the system, you don't have to do anything! You change device's orientation and the Activity is reloaded with the proper layout.

Comment: @murali_ma it will on its own... that's the point of creating the folder named that way. It works similar to the different drawable folders for different screen densities. @seretur I wonder though if a certain API level is required for this to work?

Comment: @Maximus Different densities requiere level 4 (1.6) but layout-land only level 3 (1.5)

Comment: @Thanks for clearing that up. Then it's not worth mentioning then... not sure anyone is targeting 1.5 anymore.

Comment: @Maximus, sadly here in Latinamerica there is still A LOT of Android device's with 1.5 on it.

Comment: @seretur That's actually pretty valuable information... thanks for letting me know. Opens up Market areas... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a second xml file that is the layout for the landscape version.  That file must be named the same and placed in a layout-land folder:

i.e.

Portrait:

```
layout/main.xml
```

Landscape:

```
layout-land/main.xml
```